# jqGrid and ASP.NET MVC URL posting problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a problem with jqGrid and ASP.NET MVC framework.
Namely, jqGrid is working fine, until the point when I have in address bar URL like this:

```
http://[domain]/Controller/Action
```

It gives me JS error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

When URL is like this:

```
http://[domain]/Controller
```

everything is working fine.
Properties for jqGrid are:

```
url: '/Controller',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST'
```

etc.

Has anyone else encountered with this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Dejan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the file "jquery.jsGrid.js".
The path in variable "pathtojsfiles" was missing one backslash at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting your action method needs this decoration:

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

Comment: Hi,
Yes I have this decoration. "Post" is working, the problem is when URL is like http://[domain]/Controller/Action. Without Action at the end of URL, jqgrid is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

a great post on mvc and Jqgrid with a sample.

http://arahuman.blogspot.com/2009/06/jqgrid-using-mvc-json-and-datatable.html